# In Preview.app, see image behind "keep new file?" dialog

Tags: preview

I tend to create small images in Preview, copy/paste them somewhere else, and forget to come back and save or delete the image. Then some time later I'll go to reboot and Preview wants to know if I want to keep the unsaved images. So I choose to review them, and I get this:
[image: Confirmation dialog covers the edited image]

But I can't see the image I'm supposed to be reviewing! So I resize the main window and the dialog helpfully keeps itself centered *(as of Big Sur it seems)* over the image to make sure I can never see it without canceling the process.
[image: Even when the window is huge, the dialog still covers the image]

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a way to actually review the image without canceling the process?

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to press Cancel here. However it should be easy to simply press restart again after doing this? Alternatively you can modify System Preferences > General > "Close windows when quitting apps" to *off* and it won't prompt you at all, instead returning the document to the same status when you get back.

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to hit restart again, but you may be underestimating the number of these things I tend to have lying around... I know, I should declutter, but when I'm trying to shut down in a hurry is generally not the best time. Good call on turning off "Close windows" - I'll give that. go, although of course then I'll *really* need to periodically go close some stuff down.

Comment: This issue is one that's bugged me for years, and it recently occurred to me I could resize the window and thereby see the image, which was a bit of a facepalm moment for me. Then today I was surprised to find that didn't actually work for me. Just now figured out it's a Big Sur change - in Catalina and previous the dialog is anchored to the top of the window (verified on my Catalina iMac here) so you can arrange it so you can see the image, but in Big Sur it stays centered in the window, smack bang on top of the image.